# Numbering levels of a tree

Tags: trees

I find the need to use an explicit level numbering for a tree.
i.e. in the tree:

```
    A
   / \
  B   B
 /\   /\
C  C C  C
```

should I number the level C the 3rd and A as the first, or the opposite?
As going 'up' the tree is going towards A; should the numbering reflect that as well?
 If can, please supply an authorized CS reference.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't say what you need the numbering for, so how can anyone say which numbering is "best"?

Comment: If there is no consensus on level numbering, this is a good answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "an authorized CS reference", since nobody has the authority to declare how tree levels should be numbered.

The "height" of a vertex is its distance from the root (or distance plus one; see another [question about the definition](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/32357/9550)) so it probably makes sense to start at the top in most cases.  But you should use whichever numbering is most convenient in your situation.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed that question - but here it's a different matter.

Comment: @user3675820 Yes, I linked that question because it's related, not because I think it gives the answer.